# Trying to determine the line of intersection of two planes but instead getting another plane?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors, 3d

In a class today I provided a method of finding the point of intersection of two planes that goes as follows, however it returned a plane and no one in the class could work out why. Consider the two planes - which I then rearranged:

$$ \newcommand{\tvect}[3]{%
   {\Bigl(\negthinspace\begin{smallmatrix}#1\\#2\\#3\end{smallmatrix}\Bigr)}}  \Pi_1: \vec{r} \cdot \tvect{2}{3}{4} = 4 \rightarrow  \vec{r} \cdot \tvect{1/2}{3/4}{1} = 1 $$

$$ \Pi_2: \vec{r} \cdot \tvect{4}{5}{2} = 3 \rightarrow \vec{r} \cdot \tvect{4/3}{5/3}{2/3} = 1$$

I then set both equations to be equal and rearranged:

$$ \vec{r} \cdot \tvect{4/3}{5/3}{2/3} = \vec{r} \cdot \tvect{1/2}{3/4}{1} $$

$$ \vec{r} \cdot ( \tvect{4/3}{5/3}{2/3} - \tvect{1/2}{3/4}{1}) = 0 $$

$$ \vec{r} \cdot \tvect{-5/6}{-11/12}{1/3} = 0 $$

If we rewrite $ \vec{r} $ as $\tvect{x}{y}{z}$, and calculate the dot product, we get:

$$ -\frac{5}{6}x - \frac{11}{12} y + \frac{1}{3}z = 0$$

This is obviously the equation of a plane (which I checked and all three intersect on the same line) but I would have expected it to get me the equation of the line of intersection as that is the only place where $ \vec{r} $ satisfies both equations simultaneously?

Can someone explain where I have gone wrong and an intuitive explanation for why another plane is being produced as the solution?

Answer (score 1):

The intersection of the two planes is the solution of the system of **two** equations
$$
\begin{cases}
2x+3y+4z=4\\
4x+5y+2z=3
\end{cases}
$$

The result of your manipulation is that you can substitute one of the two equation by your new equation $-\frac{5}{6}x - \frac{11}{12} y + \frac{1}{3}z = 0$, but anyway you have to solve a system with this and one of the original equations.

In other words: You have simply found another plane that intersects the given two planes in the same line, but now you have to find this line.

Can you do this?